# Finding a unitary matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following equation : 
    $ \tilde{B} = U B U^{\dagger} $

I also know both $ B $ and $ \tilde{B} $ , I just want to find the matrix U, that gives me the transformation. I tried using LinearSolve, but I can't get it into the form required by that function. Is there another way to do that?

I must note that the condition that U be Unitary is **ESSENTIAL.** I make this remark because of the interesting solutions proposed below, none of which, however, gives a unitary matrix U.

Edit: If it is of any help, the two matrices B and $ \tilde B $ are two quantum density matrices.

Edit2: I also added the two matrices here: http://pastebin.com/s3B1T0HD

Comment: If $\mathbf B$ is normal and similar to $\tilde{\mathbf B}$, then it's actually quite easy...

Comment: How big are these matrices?

Comment: smallest is 16x16. the largest case I want to test is 64x64.

Comment: Okay, let me give you something to try on your smallest case: apply `Chop[SchurDecomposition[mat, RealBlockDiagonalForm -> False]]` to both of your matrices, and check if the triangular (diagonal?) matrices produced are the same (up to roundoff and permutation). We can proceed after you do this.

Comment: This gives me a matrix of vectors, every element is a column vector. The two matrices are also very different (no 2 elements are equal).

Comment: As you'll see from the docs, `SchurDecomposition[]` returns a list of two matrices. The first matrix is the unitary factor, and the second matrix is the triangular factor (diagonal if the matrix fed to it was normal). If there are no diagonal elements (eigenvalues) in common for both matrices, then they aren't similar.

Comment: The problem is that the above function gives me back a 16x16 matrix of column vectors, though I was also expecting two matrices, and not this outcome.

Comment: That's... not supposed to happen. Can you post your two $16\times 16$ cases to pastebin and link to them here?

Comment: Ok, one thing, my smallest case is 8x8, and then I have to go all the way to 64x64 (sorry for the mistake). Since for the 8x8 case I get the same errors, I put this one here.  http://pastebin.com/vzvgTNWc and the results are here http://pastebin.com/LVynWGWx

Comment: A few pointers: 1. Underscores are not allowed in variable names. 2. Your second matrix is Hermitian (as expected); your first one isn't. This might be one reason why your attempts are not succeeding.

Comment: I was using different names for  the variables in my program, yes, they do not contain underscores. As for the second point, the second matrix I see is not unitary. Still, after I manage to solve this, I still do not know how to test as to whether the two states are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Actually, your numerical matrix is the Hermitian one; your first matrix with the exact entries is not Hermitian (and thus, the Schur decomposition does not give the expected diagonal factor).

Comment: Yes, I corrected the above comment, sorry. So after I gain two unitary matrices, how can I see if they are unitarily equivalent? (i.e. find the unitary)

Comment: That was the point of using the Schur decomposition as a diagnostic. Your Hermitian matrix gave the expected unitary and diagonal factors after the decomposition. Your non-Hermitian matrix... gave something quite different. So, the two cannot be similar, and there is no unitary transformation for those. You might want to reformulate the theory generating your exact matrix so that it is also Hermitian.

Comment: @J.M. see the edited question above. I added both matrices, now both are Hermitian. I do not get the exact same vectors with the SchurDecomposition method above.

Comment: I'm not asking you to match the vectors; I'm asking you to check if the diagonal factors of both Schur-decomposed matrices are identical (up to sign/permutation).

Comment: They are not identical. However, I applied the answer below, with P and S, and Chop[Simplify[U.Transpose[Conjugate[U]]]] // MatrixForm gives the Identity. Also taking Btilde = U.B.Transpose[Conjugate[U]] is satisfied up to the second decimal. I still have to figure out why this works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For normal matrices:

Find the unitary matrices $P$ and $S$ that diagonalize $\tilde{B}$ and $B$.

$D=P^{-1}\tilde{B}P\\
D'=S^{-1}BS\\
\tilde{B}=PS^{-1}BSP^{-1}\\
=> U=PS^{-1}$

```
B1 = {{2, 1}, {-1, -1}};
B2 = {{-2, 5}, {-1, 3}};

P = Transpose@Eigenvectors@B1;
S = Transpose@Eigenvectors@B2;
U = P.Inverse@S;

B1 == Simplify[U.B2.Inverse@U]
```

> True

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `SchurDecomposition[]` to generate the required unitary matrices. Though, this solution assumes $\mathbf B$ and $\tilde{\mathbf B}$ are similar, of course.

Comment: @paw: The procedure is not valid in general because B  and B~  might be such that they cannot be diagonalized. Example $ B $ = {{0,1},{0,0}}, $ \tilde{B} $ = {{0,0},{-1,0}} and U = {{0,1},{-1,0}}

Comment: @paw: the OP asks for a unitary matrix U. Your U is not unitary. Also in the final comparision you should use  $ U^{\dagger} $ rather than $ U^{-1} $, i.e. you missed a transposition. Hence I would reject your answer.

Comment: @ J.M. Despite of my comments I see another upvoting and the acceptance of the answer, without further discussion. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: Now I have tried the above, it does NOT give me a unitary matrix U. Does anyone have any other suggestion? I have to say that IT IS ESSENTIAL THAT U BE A UNITARY MATRIX.

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, I honestly don't know. Frankly, the OP has some fault in this: s/he did not specify if the given matrices are indeed normal or similar.

Comment: @Qubix, see my comment to Dr. Hintze.

Comment: I am not absolutely certain, but the two matrices, B and Btilde are most likely similar. Regarding the SchurDecomposition[] , it does not help. The result that SchurDecomposition[{B,$ \tilde B $}] would give me a list {q,s,t,p}, such that $ B = q \cdot  s \cdot p^{\dagger} $ and $ \tilde B = q \cdot t \cdot p^{\dagger} $ , whereas I need a decomposition of one B in terms of the other.

Comment: @Qubix, "not absolutely certain" - then can you at least explain (through an edit in your question) where the two matrices came from?

Comment: ...and no, that's not the use of `SchurDecomposition[]` I had in mind, since your problem is a bit different from the situation that requires the two-argument form.

Comment: edited. see the original question.

Comment: @ J.M. :Reply to (( @Dr. Hintze, I honestly don't know. Frankly, the OP has some fault in this: s/he did not specify if the given matrices are indeed normal or similar. )) (0) did you mean the answer to my question or do you find my remarks too critical? (1) the defiining equation is nothing but the satement that B and B~ are similar because U ist unitary. (2) the comments of the author of the OP, qubix, confirm my critical comments and leave my question open. (3) could you please  comment on the statements of my comments. one by one so we can break the deadlock ?

Comment: The condition to be fulfilled by $ B $ and  $ \tilde{B} $ must be that $ det( k I - B) $ = $ det( k I - \tilde{B}) $ , i.e. they are the same polynomials in k. In other words the eigenvalues of the two matrices must be equal. Notice that this is a weaker condition than the possibility of a tranformation to diagonal form.

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvectors space of a normal matrix are orthogonal. So in this case you can use [`Orthogonalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orthogonalize.html) to get a set of orthogonal eigenvectors.

```
H = {{1, 1 + I}, {1 - I, 1}};
{Lambda, SA} = Eigensystem[H]
UA = Orthogonalize[SA]
UAT = Transpose[UA];
DiagonalMatrix[Lambda] == ConjugateTranspose[UAT].H.UAT
```